# Must declare the scalar variable "@awayTeamName@homeTeamScore"

Tags: c#

When executing this code block:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO games_tbl (gameID, date, homeTeamName, awayTeamName, homeTeamScore, awayTeamScore) VALUES (@gameID, @date, @homeTeamName, @awayTeamName@homeTeamScore, @awayTeamScore)", con);
        
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameID", TextBoxGameID.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBoxDate.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeTeamName", DropDownListHomeTeam.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@awayTeamName", DropDownListAwayTeam.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeTeamScore", TextBoxHomeScore.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@awayTeamScore", TextBoxAwayScore.Text.Trim());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Game Added Successful. ');</script>");
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
}
```

I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@awayTeamName@homeTeamScore"

I went over the code and I do not see the mistake, any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't this `@awayTeamName@homeTeamScore` be this `@awayTeamName,@homeTeamScore`, note I added a comma between the parameters. Notice how, in your SQL statement, all of the other parameters are separated by a comma but these two are not.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...